# Find the inverse laplace transform: $\frac{1}{{{{({s^2} + 1)}^3}}}$

Tags: laplace-transform, residue-calculus

Find the inverse Laplace transform: $$x(t) = {L^{ - 1}}\left[ {\frac{1}{{{{({s^2} + 1)}^3}}}} \right]$$
with $x(t=0)=0$.

I did:
$${\left[ {{\mathop{\rm R}\nolimits} {\rm{es}}\frac{{{e^{st}}{{(s - i)}^3}}}{{{{(s + i)}^3}{{(s - i)}^3}}},i} \right]_3} = \frac{1}{{2!}}\frac{{{d^2}}}{{d{s^2}}}\left[ {\frac{{{e^{st}}}}{{{{(s + i)}^3}}}} \right]$$
$$\begin{array}{l}
 g(s) = \frac{{{e^{st}}}}{{{{(s + i)}^3}}} \\ 
 g' = \frac{{t{e^{st}}{{(s + i)}^3} - {e^{st}}3{{(s + i)}^2}}}{{{{(s + i)}^6}}} = \frac{{{e^{st}}(ts + ti - 3)}}{{{{(s + i)}^4}}}; \\ 
 \end{array}$$
$$ g''= \frac{{{e^{st}}\left[ {{t^2}{s^2} + 2{t^2}is - 6ti - 6ts - {t^2} + 12} \right]}}{{{{(s + i)}^5}}}$$
$$g''(i) = \frac{1}{{32}}\left[ {4{t^2}\cos t - 12\cos t - 12t\sin t} \right] + i\frac{1}{{32}}\left[ {12t\cos t - 4{t^2}\sin t - 12\sin t} \right]$$
$$\begin{array}{l}
\implies {\left[ {{\mathop{\rm R}\nolimits} {\rm{es}}\frac{{{e^{st}}{{(s - i)}^3}}}{{{{(s + i)}^3}{{(s - i)}^3}}},i} \right]_3} = \frac{1}{{2!}}\frac{{{d^2}}}{{d{s^2}}}\left[ {\frac{{{e^{st}}}}{{{{(s + i)}^3}}}} \right] \\ 
  = \frac{1}{2}\left\{ {\frac{1}{{32}}\left[ {4{t^2}\cos t - 12\cos t - 12t\sin t} \right] + i\frac{1}{{32}}\left[ {12t\cos t - 4{t^2}\sin t - 12\sin t} \right]} \right\} \\ 
\implies \text{REAL}\left[ {{\mathop{\rm R}\nolimits} {\rm{es}}\frac{{{e^{st}}{{(s - i)}^3}}}{{{{(s + i)}^3}{{(s - i)}^3}}},i} \right] = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{32}}\left[ {4{t^2}\cos t - 12\cos t - 12t\sin t} \right] \\ 
  = \frac{1}{{16}}\left[ {{t^2}\cos t - 4\cos t - 4t\sin t} \right] \\ 
\implies x(t) = 2\text{REAL} = \frac{1}{8}\left[ {{t^2}\cos t - 4\cos t - 4t\sin t} \right] \\ 
 \end{array}$$
However, when let $t=0$, $x(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: Mathematica says: $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\left(s^2+1\right)^3}\right](t)=\frac{1}{8} \left(t^2 (-\sin (t))+3 \sin (t)-3 t \cos (t)\right)$

Comment: What is $12/64$? Also, it looks like the $1/2$ term might be another algebra issue.

Comment: I think your mistake lies in assuming that $1/(2 i)^5=32$.  It is $1/(32 i)$.

Comment: OH yeah, Thanks Ron Gordon, i had a great mistake!!!